# Getting garbage number automatically in the array while applying Queue

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, data-structures, queue

I was trying to make a queue program on my own, but when I enqueue an element and then display the queue, I find an extra element already lying around in my queue. Also, I am not able to add the number of elements as I decided from the size of the queue because of the garbage numbers eating up space in my queue.
Here's the code for it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void enqueue();
void dequeue();
void display();

int main(){
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size of the queue : ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int choice, element;
    int queue[size];
    int front = 0;
    int rear = 0;
    while(true){
        printf("Queue Operations\nPress 1 for Enqueue\nPress 2 for Dequeue\nPress 3 for Display\nPress 4 for exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){
            case 1:{
                if(rear == size - 1){
                    printf("Overflow!\n");
                }
                else{
                printf("Enter the element you want to enqueue : ");
                scanf("%d", &element);
                queue[rear] = element;
                rear ++;
                }
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                if(front == rear){
                    printf("Underflow!\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("The element deleted is %d\n", queue[front]);
                    front += 1;
                    size+=1;
                }
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                if(front == rear){
                    printf("Queue is empty.\n");
                }
                else{
                for(int i = front; i <= rear; i ++){
                    printf("%d ", queue[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case 4:{
                exit(0);
            }
            default:{
                printf("Invalid Choice.\nTry again.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dequeue operation is wrong. First, you never need to change the `front` variable, which will/should always be zero. Second, you must *not* change the value of `size` after the array has been initialized with a given value for that.

Instead, your dequeue operation should simply move each of the remaining entries in the queue to locations at indexes one less than their current ones. You *could* do this in a loop, like this:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < rear; ++i) queue[i] = queue[i+1];
```

However, you can do this more efficiently by calling the `memmove` function:

```c
memmove(queue, queue + 1, sizeof(int) * rear);
```

Whichever way you choose, you then need to decrement `rear` after the shifts.

Also, the condition in the `for` loop for your display option should be `i < rear`, not `i <= rear`; and, your overflow check should be for `rear == size`.

Here's a rework of your code applying the corrections I have outlined above:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> // For "memmove"

int main() {
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size of the queue : ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int choice, element;
    int queue[size];
    int rear = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        printf("Queue Operations:\n"
                "Press 1 for Enqueue\n"
                "Press 2 for Dequeue\n"
                "Press 3 for Display\n"
                "Press 4 for exit\n"
        );
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                if (rear == size) { // Note: Using size not size - 1
                    printf("Overflow!\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf("Enter the element you want to enqueue : ");
                    scanf("%d", &element);
                    queue[rear] = element;
                    rear++;
                }
                break;
            }
           case 2: {
             if (rear == 0) {
                    printf("Underflow!\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf("The element deleted is %d\n", queue[0]);
                //  for (int i = 0; i < rear; ++i) queue[i] = queue[i + 1];
                    memmove(queue, queue + 1, sizeof(int) * rear);
                    rear--;
                }
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                if (rear == 0) {
                    printf("Queue is empty.\n");
                }
                else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < rear; i++) { // Note: i < rear not i <= rear
                        printf("%d ", queue[i]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                exit(0);
            }
           default: {
                printf("Invalid Choice.\nTry again.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note. The corrections I have pointed out and shown in my code implement a very primitive queue. For a so-called "circular" queue, you *would* need to keep track of both `rear` and `front`, but that is significantly more complex code (though it will run more efficiently for large queues, as it avoids the expensive memory-move operation). There are numerous blogs and websites showing how to implement such a queue; here's one: https://www.edureka.co/blog/circular-queue-in-c/

Comment: But still, can you tell me the reason for those random numbers in my queue after I add an element ?

Comment: @Zenom Your `queue` array is uninitialized, so the 'original' values it contains will be 'random' values. Also note that you can't initialize a variable-length array using the conventional, `int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};` syntax; instead, use a loop to set known values: `for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) queue[i] = 42;` (after the declaration line) and then you will see those 42 values.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the for loop

```
for(int i = front; i <= rear; i ++){
    printf("%d ", queue[i]);
}
```

is incorrect. At least you have to write

```
for(int i = front; i < rear; i ++){
    printf("%d ", queue[i]);
}
```

Also this statement

```
size+=1
```

does not make a sense because the size of the dynamically allocated array is fixed.

And the condition in this if statement

```
case 1:{
    if(rear == size - 1){
        printf("Overflow!\n");
    }
```

is also incorrect. You should write

```
case 1:{
    if(rear == size){
        printf("Overflow!\n");
    }
```

Pay attention to that you should make a circular queue. To do so you should introduce one more variable something like `full`  that is set when `rear` is equal to `front` and queue is not empty.

And that is more important it is better to introduce a structure that describes the queue.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how it can be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Queue
{
    int *a;
    size_t size;
    size_t front;
    size_t rear;
    int full;
};

int init( struct Queue *queue, size_t n )
{
    *queue = ( struct Queue ){ NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int success = 0;

    if (n)
    {
        queue->a = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

        if (( success = queue->a != NULL ))
        {
            queue->size = n;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void clear( struct Queue *queue )
{
    free( queue->a );
    *queue = ( struct Queue ){ NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
}

int enqueue( struct Queue *queue, int value )
{
    int success = queue->size != 0 && !queue->full;
    if (success)
    {
        queue->a[queue->rear++] = value;
        queue->rear %= queue->size;

        queue->full = queue->front == queue->rear;
    }

    return success;
}

int dequeue( struct Queue *queue, int *value )
{
    int success = queue->front != queue->rear || queue->full;

    if (success)
    {
        *value = queue->a[queue->front++];
        queue->front %= queue->size;
        queue->full = 0;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( const struct Queue *queue )
{
    if (queue->front == queue->rear && !queue->full)
    {
        puts( "The queue is empty." );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The queue is " );
        size_t current = queue->front;
        do
        {
            printf( "%d ", queue->a[current++] );
            current %= queue->size;
        } while (current != queue->rear);
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int is_full( const struct Queue *queue )
{
    return queue->full;
}

int main( void )
{
    struct Queue queue;

    printf( "Enter the size of the queue: " );
    size_t n = 0;

    if (scanf( "%zu", &n ) != 1 || !init( &queue, n ))
    {
        puts( "Error. Can not reserve memory for the queue." );
    }
    else
    {
        enum { Exit = 0, Enqueue = 1, Dequeue = 2, Display = 3 };

        size_t n = 0;

        do
        {
            puts( "Queue Operations\n\n"
                "Press 1 for Enqueue\n"
                "Press 2 for Dequeue\n"
                "Press 3 for Display\n"
                "Press 0 for Exit\n" );

            printf( "Your choice: " );

            if (scanf( "%zu", &n ) != 1) break;

            switch (n)
            {
            case Exit:
            {
                break;
            }

            case Enqueue:
            {
                if (is_full( &queue ))
                {
                    puts( "\nThe queue is full. You can not add a new value." );
                }
                else
                {
                    printf( "\nEnter the element you want to enqueue : " );
                    int value;

                    if (scanf( "%d", &value ) != 1)
                    {
                        puts( "You interrupted the input" );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enqueue( &queue, value );
                        printf( "The value %d is added to the queue.\n", value );
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            case Dequeue:
            {
                int value;
                if (!dequeue( &queue, &value ))
                {
                    puts( "Error. The queue is empty." );
                }
                else 
                {
                    printf( "\nThe removed element is %d\n", value );
                }
                break;
            }

            case Display:
            {
                putchar( '\n' );
                display( &queue );
                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                puts( "Invalid input." );
                break;
            }
            }

            if (n == 0) break;

            putchar( '\n' );

        } while (n != 0);

        clear( &queue );
    }
}
```

Enjoy!:)

Comment: Might be better to have a function that checks if the queue is full.  This avoids having a redundant variable and hides the implementation details.

Comment: @meaning-matters How without the variable will the function check that the queue is full?! The same condition can denote an empty queue and a full queue. And moreover if to write a function then at first you should declare a structure for the queue.

Comment: I was using rear as the variable to store the index of the last element, so why is it wrong to check `rear == size - 1` instead of `rear == size` ?(_As rear starts from 0._)

Comment: @Zenom If size is equal to 1 what does the expression rear == size - 1 denotes? Is it an empty queue or is it a full queue? And in a circular queue this will not work in any case. I showed you a circular queue in my answer. But it seems you ignored it.